# Insert icon in a tabbed page(Android) on xamarin form

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to StackOverflow community!
I need help with one problem with android in Xamarin Forms. To be precise... I tried with some friends to build our first app. We choose(with the help of our University professor) Xamarin for the cross-platform development of Android and iOS for both systems using the Xamarin Forms. I created the interface part of the app and now I am stuck in a fort with big walls. When I try to add a Tabbed Page the icon for the functional bar, the app crashes(Android) but in iOS, the problem doesn't appear...

I'd try with some solution... like :

-Render in the NameApp.Droid adds different renderer only for the android part but no result...
-Try another way to insert the icon in the .xaml file directly but no result...
-Try to follow another way to modify the .axam file for the "Theme" part 
but no result...

I want to integrate all the stuff on time only in the "Main Project". I don't want for now touch the "nameProject.Droid" or "nameProject.iOS" part, But try to make in one shoot both(Andriod & iOS). I've found a different bug in Android (è.é) but for this, I am going crazy...
But I need to modify the ".Droid" no problem I accept the challenge!

---

This is the result I aspire to create.
"https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0B6Okdz75tqQsbHJuWi04N0ZIc0E/components-tabs-usage-mobile7.png"

This is the way I add the Icon in the Tabbed Page. An assumption I add all the stuff in the "Resource" in ".Droid" and ".iOS :

```
        var MainPageTabbed = new MPageTabbed();

        var Profile = new Profile();

        var ListChat = new ListChat();

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            MainPageTabbed.Icon = "ldpi.png";
            Profile.Icon = "ldpi2.png";
            Chat.Icon = "ldpi1.png";

        }

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        {
            MainPageTabbed.Icon = "ldpi.png";
            Profile.Icon = "ldpi2.png";
            ListChat.Icon = "ldpi1.png";

        }
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false); 

        Children.Add(MainPageTabbed);
        Children.Add(Profile);
        Children.Add(ListChat);
```

---

Someone can help me please to find a solution?

Comment: This is not a Xamarin.Forms built in function. Xamarin.Forms will not take the icon and display it like in your screenshot. You will have to create a Custom Renderer (see here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for this implementation. iOS by default shows this bar at the bottom with icons. Android shows only the text in the tabs (under the nav bar). No Icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have an example of how to use the `TabbedPage` in xamarin forms:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/

... `Xamarin.forms` renders Android tabbed-pages as something called a viewpager combined with a `TabPagerStrib`, and it looks like the example in the link above.

You might read about `BottomNavigationBar` for Android instead, or look at this link for a `TabPagerStrip` with an image:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39937/adding-icons-to-a-pagertabstrip-instead-of-text

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is interested in a FontAwesome custom icon implementation I followed this tutorial to begin with: [FontAwesome with Xamarin Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p92T9djL2-U&t=294s)

Unfortunately he doesn't give an example of integrating with tabbed pages but after some experimenting I finally figured out a simplified Xaml way to render it without a custom tabbed renderer:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IBMobile.Views"
         xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
         x:Class="IBMobile.Views.HomePage"
         Visual="Material">
<ContentPage.IconImageSource>
    <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="{x:Static local2:IconFont.Home}" />
</ContentPage.IconImageSource>
```